# Using array values for nested filtering

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a nested array object

```
const product = [{
        ref_id: 'B123',
        items: [
          {
            name: 'Brush',
            ref_id: 'M1' 
          },
          {
            name: 'Paste',
            ref_id: 'M2' 
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        ref_id: 'B124',
        items: [
          {
            name: 'Apple',
            ref_id: 'M9' 
          },
          {
            name: 'Orange',
            ref_id: 'M3' 
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        ref_id: 'B113',
        items: [
          {
            name: 'Maggi',
            ref_id: 'M7' 
          },
          {
            name: 'Wai Wai',
            ref_id: 'M12' 
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

The outer ref_id is the category id and the inner one is the product id. Now, i have two array - one with values as category's ref_id and other with product's ref_id.

```
const filteredCategories = ['B123'];
const filteredItems = ['M2', 'M9', 'M7']
```

I want to filter out all items that fall under the filteredCategories ref_id and also under filteredItems ref_id which can be part of any other category. Also, the result should not contain duplicate items.

My Solution

```
let filteredProducts = [];
      products.forEach(item => {
        if(_.includes(filteredCategories, item.ref_id)) {
          filteredProducts.push(...item.items);
        } else {
          const filterProductItems = _.filter(item.items, (productItem)=> _.includes(filteredItems, productItem.ref_id));
          if(filterProductItems) {
            filteredProducts.push(...filterProductItems);
          }
        }
      });
```

Can this be done in a better and optimized way as items list can be really large?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @alia, I would suggest you use find method on product nested array object. Check for below code:

 useEffect(() => {
    getFilteredCategories()
  }, []);
    
      const filteredCategories = ['B123'];
      let filteredProducts = [];
      const getFilteredCategories = async () => {
        filteredCategories.map((id, index) => {
          const participants = product.find(o => o.ref_id === id);
          filteredProducts.push(participants)
          return filteredProducts;
        });
        console.log('filteredProducts', filteredProducts)
      }
```